# RDP from 14.04 to 14.04 failing to connect

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vinagre

I am not able to connect to a 14.04 system  from another 14.04 system using Vinagre Remote Desktop Viewer when not on the same network.

I am also not able to connect to this computer when the target is booted from a 12.04 Live CD. 
I can connect to a third computer using the same LAN cable and booted from the same 12.04 Live CD.

I am able to ping the IP address that is revealed by googling "What is my IP"
I am able to connect by clicking find when connecting from Vinagre while using the same network. (Control on WiFi from same modem as Target on Ethernet)

I have tried turning off encryption with dconf org > gnome > desktop > remote-access > require-encryption=FALSE

I have tried installing x11vnc.

When other computers work I click connect and am asked for a password. When this computer fails to connect, I do not get the password request and the screen remains black until it times out and says "Connection closed Connection to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx was closed."

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: This is the only computer to which you cannot connect when it's in another network or you cannot connect to any computer in another network?

Comment: Thanks Emil, I was able to connect to another computer, sitting right next to the one that won't connect, by entering its IP address while still on the same network. I guessed this was going outside the network and coming in via the IP.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I wasn't able to connect to a computer from outside the network. In my case the problem was that the computer was behind the router. I had to give the computer a static IP in the internal network and make the router forward all traffic from a certain port to that IP. I don't know if it's the same situation in your case, but I suspect the problem it's with the network. Another part that might be worth checking it's the firewall, maybe it has a rule of accepting traffic only from a certain network.